# By what % does monster HP increase in multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, when a player joins your game it says the monsters get stronger. What is the amount of increased HP when playing with 2, 3 or 4 people?

Comment: I agree, duplicate, but that other question may need to be updated for 2.0.  Not sure if any changes have been made but the accepted answer is from April of last year.

Comment: Yes duplicate, and yes old answer needs updates. I did a quick search but did not use the right keywords.